# Datepicker inline JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I would like to add a datepicker (datepicker-inline) into a div (not input), then I must select a date before to be able to click on a button (validate_date) . 
I tried with input, it works, but not with div. any suggestion?

```
        //Validate Date
        $("#validate_date").click(function () {
            // Make sure select a Date

            if($("#datepicker-inline").datepicker("getDate") === null) {
                $('.notyfy_container').removeClass('hidden').show();
                notyfy(
                {
                    layout: 'bottom',
                    theme: 'default',
                    text: "<?php echo $this->lang->line('select');?>",
                    type: 'error',
                    timeout: 4000, // delay for closing event. Set false for sticky notifications
                    closeWith: ['hover'], // ['click', 'button', 'hover']
                });

            }else{
                $(".notyfy_container").hide();
                $(".step2").hide();
                $('.step3').removeClass('hidden').show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: what datepicker plugin are you using? If it is jQueryUI they have demos with source code for this

Comment: I use bootstrap-datetimepicker